# Solve: $y=x+2\tan^{-1} p,$ where $p=\frac{dy}{dx}.$ (My actual question is in the body below.)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given equation is:

$y=x+2\tan^{-1} p\tag{1}.$

Well, the equation $(1)$ is of the form:

$y=xF(p) +f(p),$ which is basically the *Lagrange's equation* for ODEs of first order but not of first degree. So I proceeded as follows:

Differentiating the given equation w.r.t. $x$ and writing $p$ for $\frac{dy}{dx},$ we get:
$p=1+\frac{1}{1+p^2}\cdot\frac{dp}{dx},$ which after some simplifications and on integration gives:

$x=\ln\left(\frac{c|p-1|}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}\right)-\tan^{-1} p\tag{2}.$

Noting that elimination of $p$ is not possible between $(1)$ and $(2) $, as the method suggests I substituted the value of $x$ given by $(2)$ in $(1)$ and obtained:

$y=\ln\left(\frac{c|p-1|}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}\right) +\tan^{-1} p\tag{3}.$

As we can see elimination of $p$ between $(2)$ and $(3)$ isn't possible either so we declare that Eq.s $(2)$ and $(3)$ together form the required general solution in parametric form, $p$ being the parameter. *(This matches with the answer given in the book.)*

**Now my actual question is:**

Can't we substitute the value of $p$ from Eq. $(1),$ which is $\tan\left(\frac{y-x}{2}\right),$ in $(3)$ and thus obtain a solution which is free from $p$(i.e., to say elimination of $p$ is possible!)?

Answer (score 1):

$$y=x+2\tan^{-1} p\tag{1}.$$

$$x=\ln\left(c\frac{|p-1|}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}\right)-\tan^{-1} p\tag{2}.$$

There is a slight missunderstanding in thinking that the elimination of $p$ is not possible between $(1)$ and $(2).$

It is possible to eliminate $p$ between $(1)$ and $(2) $ : This leads to the solution expressed on the form of an implicit equation (As shown below).

What is impossible is to express the solution on explicit form $y(x)$ with a finite number of standard functions.

From $(1)$ :
$$p=\tan\left(\frac{y-x}{2} \right)$$
Then, putting $p$ into $(2)$  :

$$x=\ln\left|\tan\left(\frac{y-x}{2} \right)-1\right| -\frac12\ln\left(1+\tan^2\left(\frac{y-x}{2} \right)\right) -\frac{y-x}{2} +C$$
After simplification :

$$\boxed{y+x-\ln\left|\sin\left(\frac{y-x}{2} \right)-\cos\left(\frac{y-x}{2} \right)\right|=C'}$$
This is the solution of the EDO on the form of implicit equation.

Solving it for the explicit form $y(x)$ is not possible with a finite number of the available elementary and special functions.

Comment: Actually when we proceed to solve an ODE, we generally seeks a solution which explicitly expresses $y$ as a function of $x$ and thus get a family of curves in 2D. Similarly in case of PDEs, we try to express $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$ and get a family of surfaces. Though I agree that I have encountered implicit functions as a solution of an ODE but it is very rear. That was why, I  asked the weird question. It is always possible to have an implicit solution. I haven't gone through the detailed theory of Differential eq.s so was a bit confused (also due to my answer matched with book)

Comment: Differential equations aren't my cup of tea. So correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you!

Comment: You are right. Generaly the solution on explicit form is prefered. But when not possible explicitely a parametric solution or a solution on the form of implicit equation is accepted in the context of academic exercice. More generally the solutions of ODEs cannot be expressed even with implicit equations and have to be solved thanks to numerical methods.

Comment: So, as there exists an explicit parametric solution so we must accept that in stead of that implicit solution. Now I'm happy with that parametric solution. Thank you for your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

*Hoping that I am not mistaken*

Let $y=x+2z$ to make
$$\tan ^{-1}\left(2 z'+1\right)=z\implies 2z'+1=\tan(z)\implies\frac 2 {x'}+1=z  \implies x'=\frac{2}{z-1}$$

Comment: If I suppose $z'$ means $\frac{dz}{dx}$, then $x'$=1. And how does $2z'+1=\tan z\implies \frac{2}{x'}+1=z$? Please elaborate.. And my question was, can we substitute the value of $p$ from Eq. $(1)$ into Eq. $(3) $ to get a solution, free from $p$? As the book suggets if the elimination of $p$ is not possible between $(1) $ and $(2) $ or between $(2) $ and $(3) $ then $(2) $ and $(3) $ together form the required solution in parametric form, $p$ being the parameter.

Comment: @DhrubajyotiBhattacharjee : No, $x'$ is $x'(z)$, the derivative of the inverse function. But you are right, somehow the tangent got lost in the last two equations, $$x'(z)=\frac2{\tan(z)-1},$$ which now requires the techniques for the integration of rational expressions in trigonometric functions, usually the half-angle-tangent parametrization.

Comment: Since $z=\arctan p$ so its inverse must be $x(z) =\tan z$ where $z\in\left(-\frac π2, \frac π2\right). $ But still how does $2z'+1=\tan z \implies x'(z) =\frac 2{\tan z -1}$ ? I'm confused. Correct me if I'm wrong.